# If $f(x) =5x^2 - 2kx + 1 < 0$ has exactly one integral solution, find the sum of all positive integral values of $k$.

Tags: inequality, set-theory, quadratics, integers, discriminant

**Question :**  If $f(x) =5x^2 - 2kx + 1 < 0$ has exactly one integral solution, find the sum of all positive integral values of $k$.

**My Attempt**
Corresponding Equation of Inequality, $f(x) =5x^2 - 2kx + 1 = 0$. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the roots. $f(x)<0$ for exactly one integral value of $x$.

> Possible Graphs[image]

Conditions Required

1. $D>0 \\ 4k^2-20>0 \\k^2-5>0\\k  \in(-\infty,-\sqrt5) \;\cup \;(\sqrt5,\infty) \qquad\text{(1)}$
2. $|\alpha-\beta|\leq2 \\ |\frac{\sqrt D}a|\leq 2 \\\\ 2\frac{\sqrt{k^2-5}}{5}\leq2 \;\;\&\;\; 2\frac{\sqrt{k^2-5}}{5}\geq-2 \\\sqrt{k^2-5}\leq{5}\;\;\&\;\;\sqrt{k^2-5}\geq{-5}\\$
   Solving we get $k\in[-\sqrt{30},\sqrt{30}]\qquad{(2)}\\$
   and $k\in(-\infty,-\sqrt5] \; \cup \;[\sqrt5,\infty) \qquad\text{(3)}$

From $(1),(2),(3)$, we get $\boxed{k\in[-\sqrt{30},-\sqrt5) \; \cup \;(\sqrt5,\sqrt{30}]}$

Hence, sum of all positive integral values of $x$ is $3+4+5=12$

**Issue:** I think I have solved this problem correctly. But the answer at the back of my book is: $4+5=9$.

I mean, $\{3\}$ does not belong to the solution set, which I find strange. I might have made a mistake somewhere while solving it, but couldn't find it. I am just asking why $\{3\}$ does not belong to the solution set. Because it should, from what I see. Please help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Is it $5x^2-2kx+1=0$ or $5x^2-2kx+1<0$? (difference between your image and typed equation).

Comment: Nice nickname !

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out. The question in the image is correct

Comment: It's $5x^2$ - $2kx$ + $1$ < 0, coefficient of $x$ is -$2k$

Comment: $k=3$ does not work in the case of the inequality because no integral solution exists in this case. $x=1$ gives equality.

Comment: But why doesn't it work? That's my question. Intersection of the three intervals show that $k$ = $3$ should belong to the solution set. Is there another condition that I need to impose? Have I missed something?

Comment: You did not consider the difference between "$=0$" and "$<0$"

Comment: The condition $|\alpha - \beta| < 2$ is the mistake I think, because what if $\alpha =0.2$ and $\beta =0.9$ for example ?

Comment: $|\alpha - \beta| < 2$ is not "wrong" it is just not enough. So after you get your three values $3, 4,$ and $5$ you must put them back in the inequality and check the negative integer solution. (By your conditions, and for the values of $k$ you got, there might be either one or no integer solution for your inequality)

Answer (score 4):

We have $f(x) =5x^2 - 2kx + 1=5(x^2-2\frac{k}{5}x +\frac{k^2}{25})-\frac{k^2}{5}+1=5(x-\frac{k}{5})^2 - \frac{k^2}{5}+1 \geq  1-\frac{k^2}{5}$

So it takes it's minimum at $\frac{k}{5}$ which is $1-\frac{k^2}{5}$

We want $1-\frac{k^2}{5}<0$ in order for the inequality to have solution, hence $k<-\sqrt{5}$ and $k>\sqrt{5}$    $(1)$

The solutions to $f(x)=0$ are 
$x_1=\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2-5}}{5}$ and $x_2=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2-5}}{5}$

As you mentioned there must be the following requirement:
$x_2-x_1<2$ which by solving gives $-\sqrt{30}< k < \sqrt{30}$ $(2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get the required solutions which are $k=4$ and $k=5$

The problem with $k=3$ is that $f(x)<0$ then $x \in (0.2, 1)$ which has no integral solution

Comment: A slightly different approach, the first step. It’s beautiful, thanks for the explanation. But when I solve ($1$) and ($2$), I still get $k$ $=$ $3$,$4$,$5$ for positive integral values of $x$ that satisfy the inequality. Only after checking each of these three values separately, do we get to know that putting $k$ $=$ $3$ gets us no integral solution. I meant to ask, is there another condition that we can impose to get the correct answer directly, without checking each of the positive integral values?

Comment: Also, why is |$x_2$-$x_1$| $<$ $2$ ? Shouldn’t it be “less than or equal to $2$” ??

Answer (score 3):

Using your notations:
$$\alpha=\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2-5}}{5}; \beta=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2-5}}{5}.$$
The integral solution of $5x^2 - 2kx + 1 < 0$ must be in $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Consider only $k>0$ by the requirement and note that:
$$\\
0<\alpha<1 \iff 0<k-\sqrt{k^2-5}<5 \iff k-5<\sqrt{k^2-5} \Rightarrow k>0
$$
Hence:
$$\beta>1 \Rightarrow k+\sqrt{k^2-5}>5 \Rightarrow \sqrt{k^2-5}>5-k \Rightarrow k>3.$$
This is an additional condition that is missed by your $|\alpha-\beta|<2$.

For $k=3$, the inequality $5x^2 - 6x + 1 < 0$ has a solution $(0.2,1)$, which does not have an integral solution.

Comment: What about $\alpha =0.9$ and $\beta =1.1$ ?

Comment: @FareedAF, fair point, updated, thank you.

Comment: How can you make sure that $0<\alpha <1$ (before trying to replace $k=3,4,5$)? I mean how can we take away the cases for example where $\alpha=2.9$ and $\beta =3.6$? (I mean we know that this can't be the case here ONLY after we tried some values for $k$ right? Or did you figure it out from the form of the initial inequality?)

Comment: No need to try. It is quite observable. One can find tighter bound (range) for $\alpha$. Note that domain of $k$ is $(\sqrt{5},\infty)$ from $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is decreasing, so maximim $\alpha(\sqrt{5})=1/{\sqrt{5}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just plot the thing for $k = 4$ and $k = 5$.(Use Desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g3r9safvji), for instance); you'll see that $x = 1$ is the sole integer solution in those two cases; for smaller $k$ there are no integer solutions; for larger $k$ there are at least two.

Those plots should let you see the error in your "solution".